# OnClickListener never called with espresso perform click

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to test espresso for the first time on an existing project.
In my `HomeFragment`, contained by `HomeActivity`, I set an OnClickListener on a button that displays another view, I run the app in an emulator and everything is OK. I then want to test it with espresso and my OnClickListener never seems to be called.
I removed animation options in my emulator in developer options, but espresso tests still fail and logs confirm that onClick was never called.

> android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'is displayed on the screen to the user' doesn't match the selected view.
>
> Expected: is displayed on the screen to the user
>
> Got: "FilterPopupView{id=2131558573, res-name=filter_view, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}"

In `HomeActivityTest`

```
public class HomeActivityTest
        extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<HomeActivity> {

    public HomeActivityTest() {
        super(HomeActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        getActivity();
    }

    public void testOpenFilter() {
        Log.e("Tests", "Check button_filter is clickable");
        onView(withId(R.id.button_filter)).check(matches(isClickable()));
        Log.e("Tests", "Click on button_filter");
        onView(withId(R.id.button_filter)).perform(click());
        Log.e("Tests", "Check filter_view visibility");
        onView(withId(R.id.filter_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

In `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 130
        versionName '3.0-v2'
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 20
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

...
    
dependencies {
    // Espresso core
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        }
    // Android JUnit Runner
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        }
    // JUnit4 Rules
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        }
    ...
```

}

In `HomeFragment`

```
void initFilterButton(View view) {
    mFilterButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_filter);
    Log.e("Tests", "initFilterButton");
    mFilterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Tests", "FilterButton onClick"); // <---- Never shown in logcat
            mFilterPopupView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

In my layout 'home_fragment.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_filter"
        style="@style/FilterAccess"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/filter_access" />

    <fr.citylity.citylity.v2.ui.views.FilterPopupView
        android:id="@+id/filter_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is FilterPopupView exactly? Are you sure `initFilterButton` is called?

Comment: FilterPopupView is a custom FrameLayout. My log `Log.e("Tests", "initFilterButton")` appears in logcat but not `Log.e("Tests", "FilterButton onClick")`. I'm sure that `initFilterButton` is called but not `onClick(View v)`

Comment: I change my FilterPopupView to a simple View, the result is the same...

Comment: The error you posted clearly states, that the `FilterPopupView` has been found but it has `visibility=GONE`. So for some reason the `visibility` is not updated (when the tests are running).

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I have the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately, no... Sorry